swiper slidesPerView = auto is not woking well is there any other alternative for this?
        <SwiperComponent
          spaceBetween={20}
          slidesPerView={3}
          centeredSlides={false}
          className=" rounded-lg"
          onInit={(swiper) => {
            swiperRef.current = swiper;
            setIsBeginning(swiper.isBeginning);
            setIsEnd(swiper.isEnd);
          }}
          onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
            setIsBeginning(swiper.isBeginning);
            setIsEnd(swiper.isEnd);
          }}
          breakpoints={{
            // Mobile devices
            320: {
              slidesPerView: 2,
              spaceBetween: 10,
            },
            // Small tablets
            640: {
              slidesPerView: 2,
              spaceBetween: 15,
            },
            // Large tablets
            768: {
              slidesPerView: 2,
              spaceBetween: 20,
            },
            // Laptops
            1024: {
              slidesPerView: 3,
              spaceBetween: 25,
            },
            // Desktops
            1280: {
              slidesPerView: 3,
              spaceBetween: 30,
            },
          }}
          style={{}}
        >
          {allPackageCount?.destination?.map(
            (item: InternationalPAckageCountProps, index: number) => (
              <SwiperSlide
                className="swiper-slide"
                key={getValue(item, "id")}
              >
                <div className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center">
                  <button
                    className={`border-[1px] rounded-full px-4 py-2  ${
                      selectedIndex === index
                        ? "text-white bg-primary"
                        : "text-black hover:text-white hover:bg-primary"
                    }`}
                    onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(index)}
                  >
                    {getValue(item, "destination_name")}
                  </button>
                </div>
              </SwiperSlide>
            )
          )}
        </SwiperComponent>

   

I'm working on a React project where I need to display a list of destinations in a carousel format. Initially, I was using Swiper.js and had slidesPerView set to a fixed number (e.g., 3), and everything was working fine. However, when I change slidesPerView={3} to slidesPerView="auto", it only shows one slide per view, regardless of the screen size or content width.
Things I’ve Tried:

Setting slidesPerView to a fixed number: This works perfectly fine, but I need dynamic sizing.
Using SplideJS: I also tried switching to Splide.js, but couldn't get it to work as expected.

